# Automatically select SOM_GRID in R

Tags: r, som

I am trying to run SOM algorithm in R using Kohenen package. In this I have to define xdim, ydim dimension manually. Refer below code:

```
som_grid <- somgrid(xdim=5, ydim=6, topo="hexagonal")

som_model <- som(data_train_matrix, 
             grid=som_grid, 
             keep.data = TRUE)
```

My questions:

1. Is there a method where it automatically selects dimensions based on data
2. Can any explain logic behind this selection so that can we write function in R to identify dimensions automatically

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very well in R but I think that can help you:

```
#Consider a dummy xdim and ydim Data.
x<-c(seq(0,5,by=0.5))
y<-c(seq(0,6,by=0.5))

## Determine the sector starting and end points.
a<-rbind(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-rbind(1,2,3,4,5,6)

sectors<-cbind(a,b)

sectors

## See the table of the sector.
```

Comment: Thank you. We are trying to find xdim and ydim in Self organizing map algorithm as an input. I understood your point but we require some logic to automatically finding those dimensions. Thank you